# Determine if Cognito user is anonymous in AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

When supporting anonymous Cognito users is there an easy/efficient way to determine whether the user is an anonymous vs existing user from within a Lambda function?  I know I can get access to the cognitoIdentityId and cognitoIdentityPoolId via the context.identity property that is passed into Lambda functions.

Comment: As I remember you still get accessToken, identityToken and refresh token when signing in as an anonymous user - the identityToken is a JWT that will contain info on the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [DescribeIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeIdentity.html) from the Lambda function, this will return any logins linked to that identity id. This does need your developer credentials to be called.